# How to commit/update project from domain name in svn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I installed svn server in window 10 to commit/update my project. It works well in local LAN. However, when I go home, it can not use because it use the local ip address such as

```
https://my_computer_name:8443/svn
```

Could you suggest to me a way to map the local address to domain to use the svn checkout in my home. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't map local IP to domain. You need to get the global IP from you internet provider and use it in your svn web server configuration

Global IP could be linked with domain too.

Comment: I check it from http://checkip.dyndns.org/and it returns my global ip address such as Current IP Address: 115.xxx.xxx.xxx. It is set in my computer. I tried to connect it from my home pc as svn checkout 115.xxx.xxx.xxx:8443/project/trunk . But it did not work

Comment: I am using visual SVN server for my task

Comment: try ping 115.xxx.xxx.xxx first

Comment: I cannot ping it. I think I was wrong about global IP address.

Comment: Try to find or buy your static global IP. I think, you've better to play with it on you home pc first to find the solution.